# JAX-WS web services with SSL

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat, ssl

I am relatively new to Java and web services, and need deployment advice. I have created a set of services and tested it using the JAX-WS reference implementation on localhost using a client based on the code generated by wsimport. The set supports a user authentication (and related accounting) per service invocation using username/password in the HTTP header.

I would now like to deploy these web services on AWS, preferably using a free-trial micro instance, over a secure (HTTPS) connection, so that authentication credentials are protected in transit. I have studied the available options to find the simplest and easiest one: there is Apache Tomcat (see goo.gl/9TkQeD), Apache Axis2 and Apache CXF (see goo.gl/v9kth0 and goo.gl/dXAmaI ). I am not sure whether the latter two are standalone components or they have to be run in the context of other servers. So, with so many available alternatives, each with pros/cons, I am not sure which one to choose.

Can anyone provide a recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You would use Metro JAX-WS portable webservice, actually I use it on Jboss 4 GA and Tomcat 5 is possible migrate to latest version without problems. Security configuration with certificates (x509) and http security is very clean. You see more [here](https://metro.java.net/).

You can get a great start point [here](http://thetechtips.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/how-to-create-a-metro-jax-ws-portable-webservice/).